# How can i update an object properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

how can i update a object properly? my attempt is not working i am getting an error:"#<ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2)>",

this is my endpoint:

```
def update
    @car = Car.find(params[:id])
    @car.update_attribute(car_params)
    render json: @car
  end
```

and the params are like this:

```
def car_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description)
    end
```

this is my query in postman

put->http://localhost:3000/cars?id=9

{"title":"new title", "description":"descriptions000"}

Comment: Sidenote: Your postman request needs to be wrapped with `"post": {}` to work correctly e.g. `{"post": {"title":"new title", "description":"descriptions000"}}` because your strong_params "require" `:post`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest `update!` in cases like this.

```rb
def update
  @car = Car.find(params[:id])
  @car.update!(car_params) # <-
  render json: @car
end
```

`update!` is nice because it will raise an error when validations fail. If you use `update` (no bang) or `update_attributes`, you might silently fail to update anything, which may lead to confusing behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are trying to use `update_attribute` instead `update_attributes`.

For `update_attribute`

```
# Syntax 
update_attribute(name, value)

# example 
update_attribute(:title, 'Ferrari')
```

For `update_attributes`

```
# Syntax 
update_attributes(attributes)

# example 
update_attributes(title: "Ferrari", description: "This is my Car"})
```

Please change your endpoint as below

```
def update
  @car = Car.find(params[:id])
  @car.update_attributes(car_params)
  render json: @car
end
```

Please refer to [update_attributes](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attributes).

I hope this will help you.